# What is wrong wrong in this vba code? Set SourceRng = SourceWS.Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(650, 11))

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set SourceRng = SourceWS.Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(650, 11))
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I'd say `SourceWS.cells` would be better, but you've given no indication of why you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's no worksheet reference for either Cells instance, so they will refer to cells on the active sheet, or if the code is in a sheet module the sheet the module is for.

There are various ways to fix this, here's one,

```vb
Set SourceRng = SourceWS.Range(SourceWS.Cells(1, 6), SourceWS.Cells(650, 11))
```

another,

```vb
With SourceWS
    Set SourceRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 6), .Cells(650, 11))
End With
```

and one more

```vb
Set SourceRng = SourceWS.Cells(1, 6).Resize(650, 6)
```